# Configuração de varávies de ambiente - Comandos não funcionam - Ionic

Tags: java, node.js, ionic3, npm

Está apresentando o seguinte erro:

'ionic' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Porém esse comando aparece só no cmder, no prompt do node.js que instalei funciona "normal".
Ao criar uma aplicação com Ionic 3 não atualiza a página durante o desenvolvimento, quando salva, por exemplo.
Poder ser outro problema ou realemente é a variável de ambiente?
Segue minha configuração de variáveis de ambiente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A atualização da página após alterar um arquivo (livereload) não tem a ver com as variáveis de ambiente. As variáveis de ambiente são "atalhos" para você acessar determinados comandos.

No caso do comando `ionic`, você não precisa configura-lo nas variáveis de ambiente do Windows, basta instalar o Ionic globalmente que os comandos já estarão disponíveis para utilizar.

No terminal do Windows, execute os seguintes comandos:

1. `npm install -g ionic` (instala o Ionic globalmente)
2. `ionic start nomeDoProjeto tabs` (cria um projeto Ionic)
3. `cd nomeDoProjeto` (acessa a pasta do projeto)
4. `ionic serve`(abre uma página web com o projeto rodando)

Qualquer alteração que você fizer nos arquivos do projeto já deve fazer a página recarregar automaticamente, com essas alterações.

Referência: [Free Mobile App Development: Getting Started with Ionic Apps](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started#cli)